# Stackview will not obey constraint

Tags: xcode, storyboard, constraints, uistackview

I have 4 vertical stacks (NameStack, EmailStack, PasswordStack, ConfirmPasswordStack) and one view (CreateAccountView) embedded in a another vertical stack (FormStack) which inside a view (FormView) but the inner most stacks (NameStack, EmailStack, PasswordStack, ConfirmPasswordStack) will not obey a leading + 20pt constraint and instead stick right to the leaded edge of the FormStack.

[image: Screengrab of display & stacks/views/constraints]

When I check on the Conflicting Constraints there seems to be a phantom constraint I can't seem to find/delete (leading=NameStack.leading).

[image: Screengrab of Conflicting Constraints]

I have tried adding removing all the constraints multiple times, remove all the other inner stacks and just working with the NameStack and I can NOT get that inner NameStack to be leading + 20pt.

The desired result is below.

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it looks like you have your stack views set to `Alignment: Center` when they should be `Alignment: Fill`

A tip: when designing your UI (particularly when learning layout), give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easier to see what's going on.

For example:

[image]

- Gray: FormView
- Cyan: FormStack
- Pink: Name / Email / Password / Confirm stack views
- Green: Labels
- Yellow: Text Fields

When we run that, it will look like this:

[image]

When we're happy with the layout, we can remove the background colors:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I dont know why I didn't think of changing the background colours before! But that's been the biggest help ever!!